# running any pip commands results in an attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Pip seems to have broken all of a sudden in my virtual environment (venv). When running any pip command, (like `pip install --upgrade pip`), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 165, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 339, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 44, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 294, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 868, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 809, in find_all_candidates
    page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/sources.py", line 134, in page_candidates
    yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 769, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 604, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 509, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 125, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 454, in request
    return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 57, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 413, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 316, in get_connection
    conn = self.poolmanager.connection_from_url(url)
  File "/home/user/code/home-stuff/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 299, in connection_from_url
    u.host_ip, port=u.port, scheme=u.scheme, pool_kwargs=pool_kwargs
AttributeError: 'Url' object has no attribute 'host_ip'
```

I'm running linux mint 21 with Python 3.10. Not sure what caused this issue as the only changes I've made recently were system updates (via `apt upgrade`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around for a bit and trying a few things, I deleted my virtual environment (`rm -rf .venv`) and recreated it via `python -m venv .venv`.